# Selection of mcu

Tags: microcontroller

I wanted to learn to use mcu's.
Which is the best microcontroller to start off with?
The one that I have in mind is:
Small,
Easy to find resources for projects ,
Easy to use,
Easy to upload program to the microcontroller (doesn't require much hardware ),
Not picaxe (which is not available at my place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly all current micro-controllers can do the basic things you would want to do with a micro-controller, but each requires some startup effort to get 'up and running'.

A few possible choices:

- Arduino, maybe switch to bare AVRs later
- Microchip PIC
- Cortex M0 (LPC1114, LPC810).

IMO the importance of the initial choice is overrated. Just learn to program one of these, preferably in C or even C++. Concentrate on your program logic, not on the use of fancy peripherals or libraries, and what you learned will be easily transferred to other micro-controllers.